Braess paradox: a network counterintuitive NE graph example
I cannot understand here why switching to
$CD$ is a dominant strategy??
If $x>4500$ then it may be beneficial for a Nash-Equilibrium to go from $C$ to $B$ and not from $C$ to $D$.
And hence $CD$ is not dominant.


The authors only consider 4000 drivers/units, so x can never be larger than that.

@math-jl That's explanatory, thank you.
